# JQuery calling the input object in the function ($.each)

Tags: jquery

Hi I'd like to ask how to call the object being called into the function. For example
where `obj` has objects inside for example

```
obj = {
  "objI1": "1",
  "objI2": objII1,
  // .......
}
$.each(obj, function(index, objI2) {
  // i want to be able to call the "obj"
  // to get different parts of the object, for example:
  obj.objI3 = "hello"
})
```

how would i be going on about this?

Comment: `objII1` is not a valid JSON - is that variable you have defined somewhere ?

Comment: yes it is a object that I defined else where. So for example:

```obj = {
"objI1": "1", 
"objI2": objII1,
//......
}
objII1 = {
"Name":"fred",
"Age": 14,
// ....
}
```
So if I called ```obj.objI2.objII1.Name``` i will get "fred"

Comment: What do you mean by "call the object"? Do you just want to access each key of the object using jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your point.
Did you try your code ?
You can access `obj` inside the `$.each`.

Ex. :

```
var obj = {
    "objI1": "1",
    "objI2": {'foo':42, 'bar':6}
};
console.log(obj);

$.each(obj, function (index, data) {
    console.log(index);
    obj.objI3 = (obj.objI3 ?? 'Hello') + ' World';
    console.log(obj);
});
```

Display :

```
{objI1: "1", objI2: {…}}
objI1
{objI1: "1", objI2: {…}, objI3: "Hello World"}
objI2
{objI1: "1", objI2: {…}, objI3: "Hello World World"}
```